# Django Python3 - AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'META'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, post, django-forms

This error is occurring whilst being run...

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'META'
```

Here is my html form...

```
    <form method="POST" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label for="ticker">Ticker: </label>
    <input type="text" name="ticker"/>
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn" />
    </form>
```

Here is the contents of form.py...

```
from django import forms

class EmailForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.TextInput()
```

And here is my view...

```
    def ticker(request):
        form = EmailForm()
        context = {"form": form}
        template = "stocks.html"
        return render(request, template, context)

    ticker(request)
```

And finally my import...

```
from .forms import EmailForm
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? I'm very new to Django and need some help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What is this last line in your view?

```
ticker(request)
```

The error message is reporting that the "META" attribute is not found in an object, and AFAIK `request` is the only object in Django [having an all-uppercase `META` attribute](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META). So I think you're simply calling the view function by passing something that isn't a proper [HttpRequest object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#httprequest-objects).

You're not supposed to call your view directly, but rather [declare it in your URLconf](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request) and have it called from there.